# Ternary condition on onclick event

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a to-do application in React. Code I have so far adds to-do items to the to-do list. When I click on the edit icon I had put turnery condition for the done icon but it's not working. Can someone explain what is wrong with my code?

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TodoList from './TodoList';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function App() {
  // const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [todos, setTodo] = useState([]);
  const input = React.useRef();

  const addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = uuidv4();
    setTodo([...todos, { id: id, text: input.current.value }]) 
    input.current.value='';
  } 

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    setTodo(todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id));
  }

  const editTodo = (id) => {
    
  }

  return ( 
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input type="text" ref={input}/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={addTodo}>Enter</button>
      </form>
      <TodoList todos={todos} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} editTodo={editTodo}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TodoItem.js

```
import React from 'react'
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import DoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Done';

const TodoItem = ({todo, deleteTodo, editTodo}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon/>
                <input type="text" value={todo.text} readOnly={true}/>
            </div>
            <div>
               { <EditIcon/> ? <EditIcon onClick={editTodo}/> : <DoneIcon/> }
               <DeleteIcon onClick={deleteTodo}/>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default TodoItem
```

Comment: <EditIcon/>  will always bee there because you are importing from material ui. use some field which has status for edit or done in turnery logic.

Comment: something like that: {isEditing ? editingTemplate : viewTemplate}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. One, also pointed out by Abu Sufian is that your ternary operator will always trigger whatever is immediately after `?`, because `<EditIcon/>` is just a component and will always be true.

But more fundamentally, to do what you want, you will need to add another properly to your todo list, say, `status`. So when a task goes in for the first time, it will be in `pending` status, then once you click your Edit icon, it will change to `done`. And that's how we will toggle that icon with a ternary operator.

So I would change your `addTodo` function to

```
  const addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = uuidv4();
    setTodo([
      ...todos,
      { id: id, text: input.current.value, status: "pending" }
    ]);
    input.current.value = "";
  };
```

Then I would change your `editTodo` to:

```
  const editTodo = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    setTodo(
      todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) todo.status = "done";

        return todo;
      })
    );
  };
```

And finally, I would change your ternary part to:

```
{todo.status === "pending" ? (
          <EditIcon onClick={() => editTodo(todo.id)} />
        ) : (
          <DoneIcon />
        )}
```

Here is a complete [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-andras-11opn?file=/src/App.js) for you. Sorry I don't have your CSS so I can't make it look super pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this.

```
{ !todo.done ? <EditIcon onClick={editTodo}/> : <DoneIcon/> }
```

I believe checking whether a todo item is done or not should happen with a property of `todo` object itself.

In a ternary you need to start with a condition.

```
condition ? do something when true : do something when false
```

So you have to have a condition in the first place. In your case `EditIcon` is not a condition.

If you are looking for a way to mark a todo as completed so you need to do more things.

```
const markAsCompleted = id => {
  const todo = todos.find(todo => todo.id !== id);
  setTodo([...todos, {...todo, done: true }]);
}
```

Then you can decide based on whether a todo is done or not.